# Linear regression output "Call Formula" can't be exported to csv file

Tags: r, csv, output, linear-regression

I'm working on a for function that uses the input data to generate several linear regression models, a~c. This data generate works perfectly fine, but, I need to export the data resulting to a csv file. I'm using the tydy() and glance () functions to obtain p values, intercepts, r2 etc. That part of the code works fine, but,  the output file does not provide me with the "Call Formula:" of the linear regresion, so I'm having problem to interpret the out... Can someone tell me, please, how to make the call formula become the header of the csv file?.

Comment: Try to save the formula as a character/string variable in a new column in your data frame and then save it as a csv file. Try this simple example `library(broom);
frml = 'disp ~ hp + cyl';
m = lm(frml, data = mtcars);
dt_m = tidy(m);
dt_m$frml = frml;
dt_m`

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that csv files have a singular header that you can save the `call` to but if you simply want to capture the call to `lm` with the results then (using mtcars data since you didn't provide much context):

```
library(broom)
m = lm(disp ~ hp + cyl, data = mtcars)
xxx<-tidy(m)
xxx$call<-toString(m$call)
xxx
```

produces...

```
         term     estimate  std.error  statistic      p.value                        call
1 (Intercept) -144.5694333 37.6522356 -3.8395976 6.173165e-04 lm, disp ~ hp + cyl, mtcars
2          hp    0.2358181  0.2578106  0.9146953 3.678948e-01 lm, disp ~ hp + cyl, mtcars
3         cyl   55.0625843  9.8975401  5.5632595 5.310020e-06 lm, disp ~ hp + cyl, mtcars
```